# Google ads are not displayed in IE but visible in Firefox!

Tags: javascript, adsense

I have weird problem,

i've placed an google ads on my page and it is visible in firefox but it's not visible in IE. I tried in different systems..

I could not find the problem...

Javascript is on and google ads are no blocked and no specific ad blocker are enabled. I'm sure about that but i could not find about this issue..

My link is http://hiox.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the site in IE8
2. Press F12 for developer tools
3. Click the mouse icon on the HTML tab
4. Go back to the browser window and click the DIV above "user comments" where the ads are supposed to render
5. Go back to the Develop Tools window and look at the list of Styles (on the right) the DIV has inherited
6. Untick to disable `overflow-x: hidden` and the ads will appear
7. Fix that CSS!

Comment: I think that should done the trick.. I'll check that and will be back with results